# Adjacency list of links in web site

Tags: web-scraping, sitemap

I have to solve one problem. I have 2, 3 web sites, with a lot of connections between them. I have to find shorter way between 2 urls.
However in begining I need s.th to map this sites and makes Adjacency list that I can use. Every row should contain, one page and all connections that start from there.
I need software that can make such scan or I should write such kind of software.
It wont be so dificult with php curl for example. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need imagine your connections as graph nodes and use calculation with it? At big news website which detect named entities in news articles (http://topbitcoinnews.com) we use same approach and store our data in neo4j.org